# Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.LabelArray obsolete and supported within 32-bit processes only

Tags: vb.net, vb6, migration, progress-bar, control-array

I'm migrating an old project from `VB6` to `VB.NET` and I have faced the above warning. I also received the same warning for `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility.VB6.ProgressBarArray`. What are the nearest equivalents to these control arrays that keep the functionality of the program intact.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ProgressBar class in System.Windows.Forms namespace.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/system.windows.forms.progressbar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)